# How can I split large dataset iteratively to get smaller datasets by rows

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataset that has a column with days spanning from 1-182. I want to split this dataset into smaller 30 days data frames. However, I want the data frames to form as follows:

Dataframe 1: Day 1 - Day 30 (Row 1-30)
Dataframe 2: Day 2 - Day 31 (Row 2-31)
Dataframe 3: Day 3 - Day 33 (Row 3-32) and so on.

I already know how to split by 30 days but can't find a way to split like this! Please let me know how I can do this with some function in R

Comment: Use `embed` to create a matrix of the indices of rows you want and `apply` on that matrix to extract the relevant rows.

Comment: So you want 152 data frames as your answer?

Comment: @G5W yes! I want to keep making data frames until I reach the last day which would be the 182 day.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1could you please write out an example. I just looked by the embed documentation but don't understand how to specify 30 day periods.

Comment: @Sanam, I've elaborated on my comment as an answer.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `python` ? Also please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. You don't need to share your complete data, you can create a small fake dataset and share it with us. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on what you asked for.

```r
dat <- data.frame(jday = 1:182,
                  value = rnorm(182, 10, 1))

# window interval
windx <- 30

# iterate up until you run out of rows
res <- lapply(1:(nrow(dat) - windx), function(i) {
  dat[i:(i + (windx-1)),]
})

# 152 data.frames
length(res)
#> [1] 152

# 30 rows
nrow(res[[1]])
#> [1] 30

# look at first 6 values from first 6 data.frames
lapply(head(res), head)
#> [[1]]
#>   jday     value
#> 1    1 13.062751
#> 2    2  9.468940
#> 3    3  9.371270
#> 4    4 11.477544
#> 5    5 11.072019
#> 6    6  9.598129
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   jday     value
#> 2    2  9.468940
#> 3    3  9.371270
#> 4    4 11.477544
#> 5    5 11.072019
#> 6    6  9.598129
#> 7    7  9.349836
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   jday     value
#> 3    3  9.371270
#> 4    4 11.477544
#> 5    5 11.072019
#> 6    6  9.598129
#> 7    7  9.349836
#> 8    8 10.149530
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   jday     value
#> 4    4 11.477544
#> 5    5 11.072019
#> 6    6  9.598129
#> 7    7  9.349836
#> 8    8 10.149530
#> 9    9  9.521323
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>    jday     value
#> 5     5 11.072019
#> 6     6  9.598129
#> 7     7  9.349836
#> 8     8 10.149530
#> 9     9  9.521323
#> 10   10  9.726165
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>    jday     value
#> 6     6  9.598129
#> 7     7  9.349836
#> 8     8 10.149530
#> 9     9  9.521323
#> 10   10  9.726165
#> 11   11  8.876201

# all data.frames are 30 rows long
all(unlist(lapply(res, nrow) == 30))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is also very helpful. Will test it out.

Comment: Hope it worked for you! If it did, you can mark my answer as "the answer" to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `data.frame` like this:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(matrix(sample(20, 30, TRUE), ncol = 3))
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1   6  5 19
# 2   8  4  5
# 3  12 14 14
# 4  19  8  3
# 5   5 16  6
# 6  18 10  8
# 7  19 15  1
# 8  14 20  8
# 9  13  8 18
# 10  2 16  7
```

... create a matrix that identifies the rows of interest. Here, I'm interested in every three rows, thus 1-3, 2-4, 3-5, ... , 8-10. Change "3" to 30 for your case.

```
m <- embed(1:nrow(d), 3)
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    2    1
# [2,]    4    3    2
# [3,]    5    4    3
# [4,]    6    5    4
# [5,]    7    6    5
# [6,]    8    7    6
# [7,]    9    8    7
# [8,]   10    9    8
```

Once you have those, use `lapply` across the indices to extract the relevant rows.

```
lapply(1:nrow(m), function(x) d[rev(m[x, ]), ])
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  6  5 19
# 2  8  4  5
# 3 12 14 14
#
# [[2]]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 2  8  4  5
# 3 12 14 14
# 4 19  8  3
# 
# [[3]]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 3 12 14 14
...
...
# [[7]]
#   X1 X2 X3
# 7 19 15  1
# 8 14 20  8
# 9 13  8 18
# 
# [[8]]
#    X1 X2 X3
# 8  14 20  8
# 9  13  8 18
# 10  2 16  7
```

The result is a `list` of your `data.frame`s. You can use `list2env` if you really want to have all the subsets as separate `data.frame`s in your workspace.